# Apify Puppeteer Scraper Error: The actor run has reached the timeout

Tags: apify

Why am i getting this error message with Puppeteer Scraper?

> ACTOR: The actor run has reached the timeout of 300 seconds, aborting
>   it. You can increase the timeout in run options.

I cannot find this error in the source code.

- https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper
- https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js

Answer (score 1):

The timeout setting for the actor was set to 5 minutes (600 seconds). This can be found:

1. Select Task
2. Select Settings tab
3. Scroll down to Options
4. Set Timeout